# How to read http headers synchronously using BufferedReader?

Tags: java, http

My problem is that BufferedReader#read() creates an infinite delay until the connection is terminated. As soon as it is interrupted, immediately BufferedReader produces the result. So, because of these delays, I cannot read the headers in sync with the page load.

Comment: First observation: why are you processing raw http instead of using the appropriate API?

Comment: @g00se Yes, I've seen the standard classes, but I want to make my own link handler (localhost:80/logIn/$username@$password )

Comment: Well, if you must reinvent the wheel, the thing to do is to find out the nature of the wheel, such that you know where to stop reading, resulting in a call that does *not* block on IO

Comment: @g00se If you think that I'm trying to "reinvent the wheel", can you suggest some APIs to implement my idea? :)

Comment: Your BufferedReader is the TCP connection and it can have a number of HTTP requests before it terminates (if it will at all). To read a single HTTP header, and not have it break after the first request, you must have a HTTP request parser to know where request starts (HTTP/1.1) and where it ends (CRLF after the body content.) And the body content may not even have a Content-Length and/or may be chunked encoding. And even trailer HTTP headers. If it's HTTP/2.0+, then you need whole another parser in binary.

Comment: @JonathanRosa You misunderstood my problem, BufferedReader #read() hangs not after getting all the headers, but before the first character. For example, I made the following code:
`
int b = -1;
while (  (b = reader.read() ) != -1){
  System.out.print((char)b);
} 
`
And as a result, the console is empty until I cancel the page load in the browser. As soon as I do this, the console is immediately filled with headers.

Comment: The effect you're mentioning is difficult to diagnose without knowing what you're doing. It seems to involve a web page, your Java app *and* a browser in some way…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BufferedReader is not the solution, as the name implies, it *buffers* data by *N* bytes or until end of stream (when socket is closed) ["for the efficient reading of characters, arrays, and lines.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)" If your BufferedReader is just socket.getInputStream(), then use that.

```java
int b = -1;
while ((b = socket.getInputStream().read()) != 1) {
    System.out.print((char)b);
}
```